# How can I echo the results of the featured video plugin other than where it does by default?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a plugin that is called Featured Video. When creating a post in Wordpress, you just add the video's url into the widget in the sidebar and it's results echo under your inputed text from the WYSIWYG editor. I'm not the best with php. I was looking to see how and where the plugin works and inserts itself into the post.

I want to echo the results elsewhere on the post. Is this the code I should be concerned with?

```
function get_the_post_video($pid = null, $width = '560', $height = '315', $wmode = 'transparent', $allowfullscreen = true){

    if($pid == null){
        global $post;
        $pid = $post->ID;
    }

    $id = get_post_meta($pid, 'fv_video_id', true);
    $video = get_post_meta($pid, 'fv_video', true);
    $width = strval($width);
    $height = strval($height);

    echo $video;
    if($id != null){
        if(is_vimeo($video)){
            $fs = get_allow_full_screen($allowfullscreen, true);
            echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$id.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" frameborder="0" '.$fs.'></iframe>';
        }else{
            $fs = get_allow_full_screen($allowfullscreen);
            echo '<iframe width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id.'?wmode='.$wmode.'" frameborder="0" '.$fs.'></iframe>';
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you link the specific plugin you're using so we can be sure of the right one?

Comment: Sure thing https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-video-lightbox/